# To change the URI to JSON

Tags: json, uri

I need to get the URI as,

```
list=Test&data=%7B%22email%22%3A%22example%40gmail.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22example%22%7D&api_user=username&api_key=password
```

So what would be the json format?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You want to convert the `data=%7B%22email%22%3A%22example%40gmail.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22example%22%7D` into `{"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"}`

Comment: then where is data?  
"data":{"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"} is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question then.

Comment: i want to change data={"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"} into json format.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment

> i want to change data={"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"} into json format

I guess you want:

```
{
   "list": "Test",
   "data": {
      "email": "example@gmail.com",
      "name": "example"
   },
   "api_user": "username",
   "api_key": "password"
}
```

Comment: No, i'm getting error like {"error": "error in data: is not a valid json string"}, Your mail id please.

Comment: Well the string above is valid JSON, no idea what kind of tool or service you are using, but you can validate your json here as example: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Yes, I think yourone is validated string. But for this particular string  data={"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"} that is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't understand what you issue is. What service or application are you using that gives you this error? Are you trying to send the JSON to a server in a GET in the URL? And if yes, are you sure you don't want to POST it to that url?

Comment: Thank you for your response, you answer is valid string, but in my case it is expecting in different type, Now I solve that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
{
list:"Test",
data:%7B%22email%22%3A%22example%40gmail.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22example%22%7D，
api_user:"username",
api_key:"password"
}
```

the field 'data' is also a string

Comment: The original string of data=%7B%22email%22%3A%22example%40gmail.com%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22example%22%7D‌​ is data={"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"}. So what would be the json format for the data={"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"} ?

Comment: { list:"Test", data:{"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"}， api_user:"username", api_key:"password" }Does this work?

Comment: No, i'm getting error like {"error": "error in data:  is not a valid json string"}.

Comment: Please wait, let me have a try.

Comment: data:[{"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"}] And this?

Comment: I think that you should escape the string {"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"example"}

Comment: Thanks for your response. Above answer is valid string, but in my case it is different. Thanks :)